# Jwplayer: Firefox + HTML5 + mp4

Tags: video, jwplayer, mp4, jwplayer7

I am using jwplayer 7.2.4 for playing videos. I offer 2 mp4 versions of the video. Here ist the config of the jw-player:

```js
jwplayer("hwdvscontainer").setup({
     playlist:[{
      image:"xxxx/xxxx.jpg",
      sources: [{
       file:"xxxxx/xxxxx_low.mp4",
       label: "SD"
      },{
       file:"xxxx/xxxx.mp4",
       label: "HD"
      }],
                                                mediaid: "zpVXiBDZ"
     }],
     height:"371",
     width:"660",
     startparam: "start",
     skin: {
                                            name: "seven",
                                            active: "#CCCCCC",
                                            inactive: "white",
                                            background: "rgba(133, 116, 101, 0.85)"
                                        },
     primary: "html5"
     
       });
```

This setup works on every player, but not in Firefox. With flash installed everything is working fine, but without not.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Harald

Comment: What's your OS and Firefox version?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Firefox's  **[Browser Compatibilty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility)** notes you will see that it supports MP4 but it comes with footnotes...

> [10] To avoid patent issues, support for MPEG 4, H.264 and MP3 is **not
>   built directly** into Firefox. Instead **it relies on support from the OS
>   or hardware** (the hardware also **needs to be able to support the profile
>   used** to encode the video, in the case of MP4). Firefox supports these
>   formats on the following platforms: Windows Vista+ since Firefox 22.0,
>   Android since Firefox 20.0, Firefox OS since Firefox 15.0, Linux since
>   Firefox 26.0 (relies on GStreamer codecs) and OS X 10.7 since Firefox
>   35.0.

In short, it's 50 / 50 whether your Firefox will play the video. Even if it did work for you, it may not work for your site visitor(s) and their version of Firefox combined with their Operating System.

**To fix :**
The guaranteed video format for playback in Firefox is **OGV** (aka **OGG**).

To convert your MP4 to OGV you can try this **[free online converter](http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-ogg)**. Or find another online.

Now I don't use JWPlayer so I can't tell you how to add multiple format files, but this **[top answer](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/6062481-multiple-video-formats-for-html5-fallback-)** on their forums might help you. Away from JWPlayer, using the standard HTML5 video tag it looks like :

```
<body>
<video width="700" controls loop>

  <source src="myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"> <!-- For Other Browsers -->
  <source src="myVideo.ogg" type="video/ogg"> <!-- For Firefox -->

</video>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

JW Player has a long running issue with playing media in Firefox where the path to the media uses a "relative" or protocol agnostic URL (starts with "//").

This has now supposedly been fixed in JW7.4+

The solution, if using an earlier version of JW Player, is to ensure you are using a fully qualified URL to your media.

**Update:**

Just checked this out with JW7.4+ and they appear to have actually broken it again!

```
JW 7.1.0 - Worked;
JW 7.2.0 - Broken;
JW 7.3.0 - Fixed it;
JW 7.4+ - Broke it again...
```